# Teapot Riddle no.33

Tags: riddle, word

Seeing as Teapots are the puzzle of the day, i thought i'd give it a go,

I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

> My first teapot is supporting
>
> My second teapot is a bit of a turn on
>
> My third teapot you'll get a kick out of
>
> My fourth teapot contains a spare

hopefully its not too easy, i can always add hints later if required

Comment: is Contains a spare ? should it be written like this?

Comment: Apologies Jannis, I've corrected that

Comment: no need to, I do misstakes all the time. Just correct it, or don't do, I don't mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your teapots are

> boots.

```
My First Teapot is supporting
```

> If you are wearing boots then they support your feet.

```
My second Teapot is a bit of a turn on
```

> "Booting" is what your computer does when you turn it on.

```
My Third Teapot you'll get a kick out of
```

> Like the last one, this is verb rather than noun: to boot something is to kick it.

```
My Fourth Teapot is Contains a spare
```

> The boot of your car.

Discarded teapots:

> The second could have been more literal -- some boots are designed to be sexy and some people are very much into that sort of thing. The third could have been a reference to football boots or to "kick boots". (I got #2 right on my own but needed some prodding from OP to get #3.)

Comment: Great answer! Especially like your second explanation! :)

Comment: I'm inclined to accept this as the answer as it got the closest with the clues, the second clue is your second meaning, but the third is incorrect,

Comment: I don't think either El-Guest or I will be offended whichever answer you accept.

Comment: for the third hint: (rot13) Vs lbh obbg fbzrguvat vg zrnaf gb xvpx vg, gur glcr bs fubrf vf abg vzcbegnag, lbh pna fgvyy obbg fbzrguvat onersbbg fb abg gur fnzr zrnavat

Comment: @BladeWraith your puzzle, your choice on acceptance. I agree with Gareth, pick the answer that you envision to be closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: You edited third is still not there

Comment: It is now. Thanks for the glorious green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Boot?

My First Teapot is supporting

> Could refer to a boot cast?

My second Teapot is a bit of a turn on

> Maybe the musical Kinky Boots? (Or as noted by @Gareth McCaughan, booting up a computer)

My Third Teapot you'll get a kick out of

> Kick out of, because it’s on your feet

My Fourth Teapot is Contains a spare

> As in the spare tire in the trunk of a car

Comment: REALLY!!!! 3 minutes that's all it took! well played my good sir, care to explain the hints to everyone?

Comment: Your answer was posted about 30 seconds before mine, but I decline to delete mine because mine has at least 30 seconds' worth of explanation that yours lacks :-).

Comment: ... as we can see from the fact that your edit with explanations was about a minute later than my answer :-).

Comment: First hint is close enough, and fourth is correct, apologies i know its the british name for it. the 2nd and 3rd however are incorrect