# Teapot Riddle no.36

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot Riddle 36 already

The neverchanging rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
Try to figure out the word with my hints.

First Hint:

> My first teapot should be done everyday
>   My second teapot is every 0.5 to 10 seconds
>   My third teapot is every year

Second Hint:

> My first teapot is more and more done by machines
>   My second teapot is more or less not changing
>   My third teapot is changing rapidly

Third Hint:

> My first teapot affects humans, cars and dishes
>   My second teapot affects ships
>   My third teapot affets nations

Final Hint:

> My first teapot is a task with water
>  My second teapot is water
>  My third teapot doesn't have to be water

Good luck and have fun :)
Last riddles:
[35](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73075/time-for-another-teapot-riddle-no-35)
[34](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73022/teapot-riddle-no-34-strikes-again)
[33](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72941/teapot-riddle-no-33)

I want to recommend making teapot riddles to everyone :)
*And linking last riddles =_=*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems similar to @NaeemShaikh's answer but its all I can think of.

Is it

> Wash  (cleaning/wave action/rainstorms)

My first teapot should be done everyday 
My second teapot is every 0.5 to 10 seconds 
My third teapot is every year

> Cleaning should be done daily
>  The washing action of waves is periodic, though I think the range is higher than given 
>  Storms can be seasonal

My first teapot is more and more done by machines
My second teapot is more or less not changing
My third teapot is changing rapidly

> Cleaning cars, dishes, etc are done quite commonly by machines
>  the waves lap up against the shore, beating their gentle rhythm throughout time
>  Rain/storms/etc patterns change constantly

My first teapot affects humans, cars and dishes
My second teapot affects ships
My third teapot affects nations

> yes, cleaning humans, cars and dishes and other things is common
>  the wash of the waves does affect ships
>  Storms/Monsoons/etc do affect nations

Hidden hint

> You clean with water
>  the wash of waves is water 
>  Storms can be hail or snow...er.. which is water.  not sure here.

Comment: It's right: second teapot is wash : some kind of wave hitting the ship. third teapot is (to) wash away, in the right context of rain/monsoon/flood - great Job, i  think i was just explaining too confusing for anybody here

Answer (score 1):

I can only relate this word with your 1st and 3rd teapot.

Is it:

> Shower

First Hint:

> **My first teapot should be done everyday** - Bath, Cleaning (Shower)
> **My third teapot is every year** - Monsoon(Rain, shower) - Once a year

Second Hint:

> **My first teapot is more and more done by machines** - Auto car wash, Automatic shower
> **My third teapot is changing rapidly** - Rainfall in many areas of the world is changing rapidly due to global warming

Third Hint:

> **My first teapot affects humans, cars and dishes** - like washing, bathing
> **My third teapot affects nations** - Heavy/Low rainfall

Final Hint:

> **My first teapot is a task with water** - Shower, Bath, Cleaning
> **My third teapot doesn't have to be water** - Snow, Water

Comment: That's not the word I'm searching for. But it comes pretty close :) Nice to see you again :D.  When do you make your own riddle? The third teapot affects also the mind

Comment: @Jannis.. very less.. i will create one this week

Comment: You said my word 2 times in your explanation

Answer (score 1):

Once again, I'm sure (know) I'm wrong, but are you:

> Wave (greeting/water wave/political fluctuate causing "chaos") - I'm pretty sure someone has already used this...

First Hint

> You should greet people every day
> Seems more or less like the time between waves breaking in my experience (0.5s is too fast though...
> In the US, there are elections every two years, but maybe somewhere else it's yearly?

Second Hint:

> More human-like robots!!!!
> Ocean waves are pretty constant
> This is sort of the definition of my third teapot

Third Hint:

> You can greet humans, hail taxis, and....... I guess you can wave at dishes, but why?
> Waves affect ships - from seasickness for passengers to capsizing
> Political chaos/change affects nations

Final Hint:

> ..... umm..... 60% of your body is water, so you are waving water...?
> By definition, this wave is water
> Political chaos doesn't have to involve water :P

Comment: It's not the right word, and I was the one making the teapot with wave as solution. As a tip my word is verb when you think normally of it / the most used teapot of this word is a verb

Comment: @Jannis I thought it was you (but didn't want to go back through to confirm lol).  Hmm... I'll rethink it!

Comment: WHO WAS ME!? / stop stalking me :P, where was I ?